# Why is "keyframes method" not working the way it should in my css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

In the *keyframes* part, my PC doesn't recognize the *from* part. If it would, it would be **blue** and the *opacity* command would be **grey**. But as you see none of them is correct and I don't know why. Because of this little error, my **HTML** website is not working the way it should. Can anyone please help me? I would like to finish my HTML website.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  animation: bgcolor infinite 20s;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Yeseva One', cursive;
  font-size: 4em;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

@keyframes bgcolor {
  0% {
    background: #f1c40f;
  }
  10% {
    background: #f39c12;
  }
  20% {
    background: #e67e22;
  }
  30% {
    background: #d35400;
  }
  40% {
    background: #e74c3c;
  }
  50% {
    background: #c0392b;
  }
  60% {
    background: #e74c3c;
  }
  70% {
    background: #d35400;
  }
  80% {
    background: #e67e22;
  }
  90% {
    background: #f39c12;
  }
  100% {
    background: #f1c40f;
  }
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'IM Fell DW Pica', serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Clicker Script', cursive;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

button {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display SC', serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}

button {
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  background: #ea1538;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: .3s
}

button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 8vh;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-left: 25%;
  padding-right: 10%;
}

.logo {
  color: white;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav-links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 5px;
}

.burger {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 5px;
}

span {
  color: #000000;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 19px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #000000;
  transition: .2s;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
  .nav-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 60%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ffeaa7;
    /*just to see if the slider works*/
    right: 0px;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 18vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 40%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .burger {
    padding-left: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
}

.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

@keyframes navLinkFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, it might be helpful to reframe it, with a minimal reproducible example. See [StackOverflows MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

I don't see you calling the animation anywhere in your code.   You need to target the nav links, and tell it to use the animation `navLinkFade`.

#### Here is an example of a super simple animation.

```css
ul {
  animation: fade 3s forwards;
}


@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I can't really code html and css myself, so I watched a video about responsive navigation bars. https://youtu.be/gXkqy0b4M5g . I can't really change the code by myself, cause I think I am going to make some mistakes. I don't remember that the youtuber called the animation. I think I did the some code as he did.

Comment: Check out the time code 25:20.   

The logic that he writes there is why your links aren't animating.

Comment: Thank you, good sir, for helping me! My code wouldn't work now, but thanks to you it is. Thanks for your help and your time. :)))))

Comment: I’m glad it’s working! It wouldbe heat if you could accept my answer.

Comment: Oh, Sorrry I didn't know about that. I'm really new at this page. But will do :D